# INNER JOIN WITH DELETE

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I want to make this query on oracle but I got

```
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

DELETE  FROM DYNAMIC_EXTRACT_DETAILS  DED
INNER JOIN DYNAMIC_CATEGORIE_DETAILS  DCD ON DCD.CATEGORIE_EXTRACT_ID = :i_id_categorie
WHERE EXTRACT_JOIN = DCD.CATEGORIE_EXTRACT_JOIN AND DED.EXTRACT_ID = :i_id_extract
```

There is a solution ? Thanks for helping

Comment: Hint : MERGE into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also phrase your delete using a correlated subquery:

```
DELETE
FROM DYNAMIC_EXTRACT_DETAILS DED
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM
              DYNAMIC_CATEGORIE_DETAILS DCD
              WHERE DED.EXTRACT_JOIN = DCD.CATEGORIE_EXTRACT_JOIN AND
                    DCD.CATEGORIE_EXTRACT_ID = :i_id_categorie) AND
      EXTRACT_ID = :i_id_extract;
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try merge into -

```
MERGE INTO DYNAMIC_EXTRACT_DETAILS
USING DYNAMIC_CATEGORIE_DETAILS
ON (DCD.CATEGORIE_EXTRACT_ID = :i_id_categorie)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
     DELETE
WHERE EXTRACT_JOIN = DCD.CATEGORIE_EXTRACT_JOIN AND DED.EXTRACT_ID = :i_id_extract;
```

Comment: That won't work; you first need to update the row before you can delete it in a merge statement.

Comment: @Boneist, Is it mandatory to use UPDATE statement? Alone Delete will not work? Actually I have never tried alone delete statement before thats why I was too curious about this.

Comment: Yup, you need to update the row before it's visible to the delete part. From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9016.htm#sthref6559): `Specify the DELETE where_clause to clean up data in a table while populating or updating it. The only rows affected by this clause are those rows in the destination table that are updated by the merge operation.` Bear in mind that the delete statement sees the updated values, not the original values.

Comment: So the merge statement in your answer is going to have to do an update before it does a delete, which makes it a more expensive option than just doing the delete, as per Tim's answer. N.B. in some situations it might make more sense to do the update-then-delete in the merge statement, but the fact that you may be doing unnecessary work means it needs to be considered carefully.